# How does CPython implement os.environ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-internals

I was looking through [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/os.py) and noticed that it references a variable `environ` in methods before its defined:

```
def _createenviron():
    if name == 'nt':
        # Where Env Var Names Must Be UPPERCASE
        def check_str(value):
            if not isinstance(value, str):
                raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
            return value
        encode = check_str
        decode = str
        def encodekey(key):
            return encode(key).upper()
        data = {}
        for key, value in environ.items():
            data[encodekey(key)] = value
    else:
        # Where Env Var Names Can Be Mixed Case
        encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
        def encode(value):
            if not isinstance(value, str):
                raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
            return value.encode(encoding, 'surrogateescape')
        def decode(value):
            return value.decode(encoding, 'surrogateescape')
        encodekey = encode
        data = environ
    return _Environ(data,
        encodekey, decode,
        encode, decode)

# unicode environ
environ = _createenviron()
del _createenviron
```

So how does `environ` get setup? I cant seem to reason about where its initialized and declared so that `_createenviron` can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR search for `from posix import *` in `os` module content.

The `os` module imports all public symbols from `posix` (Unix) or `nt` (Windows) low-level module at the beginning of `os.py`.

`posix` exposes `environ` as a plain Python `dict`.
`os` wraps it with `_Environ` dict-like object that updates environment variables on `_Environ` items changing.